# ES6 javascript in yeoman

Tags: yeoman, angular-fullstack

I am using yeoman angular-fullstack generator for writing webapps. However, I want to stick to the older structure instead of the recent changes with Babel/Typescript options.

I tried installing older versions of `generator-angular-fullstack` as far as 1.0.0 using npm but still end with Babel/Typescript options to choose from.

How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install angular-fullstack, just add the version after with the @ tag. 
Example : npm install -g generator-angular-fullstack@2.0.13
To see all the version, you can go on the github page and search for branch with the tag.
The same problems happens to me. I think you should adapt yourself to the new structure. You can write pure javascript in babel file. It should not scare you. 

I hope this can help you. 
Good luck!!